# What's this aircraft in the background?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I took this photo from the Wikipedia entry on [afterburners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterburner). What's the circled aircraft in the background behind the Phantom?

[image]

Comment: What museum was this photo taken at?

Comment: @CarloFelicione Prague Aviation Museum I guess. I cross-reference the list of museums with both a Mig-23 (whose afterburner we are seeing) and a Saab Draken (left).

Comment: @DarthPaghius It is the Deutsches Museum (Flugwerft Schleissheim), in Munich

Comment: @DarthPaghius the large number of German registrations should be a clue, as well as the SP on the F-4 which indicates the aircraft was stationed at Spangdalem AB in Germany as part of USAFE.

Comment: @jwenting It could've been the 'German planes' wing from just about any aviation museum...

Comment: @Mast given the sheer number of German registrations, a German museum is most plausible. Take a look at say Duxford and it's mostly UK registrations, Ottawa has mostly Canadian registrations, Lelystad mostly Dutch, it's a recurring theme. Prague would have mostly Czech I presume (never been to that one).

Comment: Now that we know the plane is a German prototype it really makes sense for it to be a German museum.

Comment: Naturally. Hindsight is 20/20.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The aircraft (I presume you mean what’s visible behind the green F-4 Phantom in the right of the photograph) appears to be a rare surviving prototype of a [Dornier Do31](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Do_31) VTOL transport aircraft.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's probably it! Looks distinctive enough not be mistaken with anything else.

Comment: I've seen this beast in the Deutsches Museum, Museumsinsel in Munich several times in the past. Good to see they moved it indoors.

Comment: That spike projecting from the nose of that plane is rather impressive.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: first aircraft in history whose primary armament was a tusk. :-)

Comment: Seems as trying to use it would be about as deadly as a bee using it's stinger.